# How to have 1 jQuery file with functions used on different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

So I am trying to keep all my functions in 1 jQuery file. Still learning jQuery btw

However I'm running into problems where a div id doesn't exist on a different page and it throws and error. I use the [**Pop Easy modal plugin**](http://thomasgrauer.com/popeasy/). I call `$('.modalLink').modal()` to initialize the plugin. It works on my home page, but will raise error on my FAQ page because there is no div with `modalLink` class.

[image: Object has no method 'modal']

I don't want to create separate files, so how would you re-write this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // PopEasy on Home Page
    $('.modalLink').modal({
        trigger: '.modalLink',          // id or class of link or button to trigger modal
        olay:'div.overlay',             // id or class of overlay
        modals:'div.modal',             // id or class of modal
        animationEffect: 'fadeIn',      // overlay effect | slideDown or fadeIn | 
        videoClass:'video',             // class of video element(s)
        close:'.closeBtn'               // id or class of close button
    });

    /*... other code for other pages go below  ....*/

    // Register Page
    $('.login-window input').on('click focusin', function() {
        this.value =  '';
    });

    // FAQ Page
    //  FAQ sidebar menu
    $('#faq-btn-general').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().addClass('faq-blue');
        $('#img-general-on').show();
        $('#img-general-off').hide();
        $('#dl-general').fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
    });

});
```

Comment: Check `document.location`?

Comment: refer the same file in all the pages. I mean add `<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/your/jsFile.js'></script>` block in all the pages.

Do not worry about missing elements. Jquery returns empty collection if there is no match found for a selector. So, nothing bad will happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no method `.modal()`, then that is probably because you don't have the proper library loaded to support the `.modal()` method.

For a well behaved jQuery method (which I assume `.modal()` is), there should be no problem with:

```
$('.modalLink').modal();
```

if the `.modalLink` object doesn't exist.  The `$('.modalLink')` jQuery object will be empty and calling `.modal()` on it will just do nothing (or that's how jQuery methods are supposed to be written anyway).  If the `.modal()` method is not well behaved, then you can protect it yourself with this:

```
// makes sure the .modalLink object exists and that the `.modal()` method exists
var modalObj = $('.modalLink');
if (modalObj.length && modalObj.modal) {
    modalObj.modal(...);
}
```

Comment: I have the .modal jquery, what I mean is there is no actual .modal div on the FAQ page, or any other page except for the homepage, that's where my problem lies

Comment: Thanks! This looks like the cleanest and most proper solution :) the PopEasy modal must have not be 'well behaved'.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking to see if the objects exist before adding events to them

You can do so with this.

```
if ( $('#myDiv').length ){}
```

So to replace some of your code it would look like this

```
if ( $('.login-window input').length ){
    $('.login-window input').on('click focusin', function() {
        this.value =  '';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test is method exists such as

```
if ($.fn.modal) {
    $('.modalLink').modal({
        trigger: '.modalLink',          // id or class of link or button to trigger modal
        olay:'div.overlay',             // id or class of overlay
        modals:'div.modal',             // id or class of modal
        animationEffect: 'fadeIn',      // overlay effect | slideDown or fadeIn | 
        videoClass:'video',             // class of video element(s)
        close:'.closeBtn'               // id or class of close button
    });
}
```

But that can be long.... You can also add an ident class on the body that you check in the javascript file.

if ($('body').hasClass('forum-section')) {
   // Include code concerning that section only
}

Hope that helped

Comment: Please note that i use "if ($.fn.modal) {}" to see if the "modal" function has been included already.  Previous answers concerned if ($(obj).length) which is also a good solution.  But let's say that $('.modalLink') exists but not the function "modal()", then the error still gonna show up.

Comment: Oh I do use different body id's, trying this out now

Comment: then make sure you condition looks like this : if ($('body').attr('id') == "forum-section") {} OR if ($('#forum-section').length) {}

Comment: Thanks this also worked wonderfully! But going with @jfriend00's answer because I think it gets to the core of the problem. I do see myself using your technic on some other functions tho :) upvoting!

Answer (score 1):

try something like:

```
if ( $('.myClass').length > 0){
  $('.myClass').modal(....)
}
```